# How can you wake an incapacitated guard?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In MGSV:TTP, if you stun or tranquilise a guard, is there any way you can wake him up?

In Peace Walker you could tap a sleeping or stunned guard, but can't find anything like this in Phantom Pain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can kick them to wake them up**

Stand over a stunned or sleeping target and press the attack/CQC button (on PS4 - R2). Snake will now perform a kick to wake the guard. Watch out for nearby guards, though, because they can hear this!

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do to wake someone up, is kick them. Just stand above their unconscious body, and press the CQC button. Make sure you face the right direction, or Snake will kick the air instead.

Be careful with piles of unconscious guards, though. You probably don't want to wake them all at the same time.

Comment: You could add that if you accidentally wake a guard, you can hold them up before they manage to stand up.

Comment: @kviiri Well, really, the CQC prompt appears again (the guard leaves "invulnerability") before they can stand up and become fully oriented again. So if you are close enough to hold them up you can just put them in another restraining hold.